# How to create a new table and export it as csv?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have this as my sql script.
How do I actually create a new table so that I can export as a csv?

```
SELECT *

FROM `db`.tableParent1

INNER JOIN tableParent2
ON tableParent1.req_id=tableParent1.req_id

INNER JOIN tableParent3
ON tableParent1.req_id=tableParent3.req_id

UNION ALL

FROM `db`.tableChild1

INNER JOIN tableChild2
ON tableChild1.req_id=tableChild2.req_id

INNER JOIN tableChild3
ON tableChild1.req_id=tableChild3.req_id
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you would want to write to a table rather than writing directly to csv?

Comment: I tried to output as csv but the format is wrong.

Comment: I wonder what wrong means. If you send the data to a table you are still going to have to write a select query to push the data to CSV.

Comment: I found out that most of the data consist of character I cant use as the deliminator, and the data consist like an email or image.

Comment: You have absolutely no control over the text in emails and I don't think csv files are appropriate for images. Perhaps you need a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating a new table from a query, you need to put "CREATE TABLE NAME as QUERY"

```
CREATE TABLE NAMEOFTABLE
AS
    SELECT *
      FROM db.tableParent1
           INNER JOIN tableParent2
               ON tableParent1.req_id = tableParent1.req_id
           INNER JOIN tableParent3
               ON tableParent1.req_id = tableParent3.req_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
      FROM db.tableChild1
           INNER JOIN tableChild2 ON tableChild1.req_id = tableChild2.req_id
           INNER JOIN tableChild3 ON tableChild1.req_id = tableChild3.req_id
```

In order to export your table as csv, please follow the next [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-export-table-to-csv/).

.